# CSS for image like in facebook and other social media

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to make a "Profile Picture" thing on my website. i just don't get how to generate it perfectly without making the picture stretch or pixelated here is my sample code by the way I'm using bootstrap as my css framework.

```
<div class="center-block" style="background-image:url(img/1.jpg);
            width: 200px;
             height: 200px;
             background-size: cover;
             display: block;
             border-radius: 100px;
             -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
             -moz-border-radius: 100px;">
```

Comment: those things from fb, and other social media combines image manipulation and cropping of the images. they don't just stretch or set the image dimensions upon upload.

Comment: exactly sir.. that's what i figuring out right now how do they process it. What to do and how to do it but I'm having my own research I'm just trying my luck here.

Comment: you could try centering the image inside a fixed width and fixed height div then set the image `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` - this way, the image wont stretch

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images bootstrap's image helper classes may be able to help a lot for your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this we can make any style with play around CSS...

```css
div {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}
.profile_1 {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.profile_1 img {
    max-width: 120px;
    max-height: 120px;
}
.profile_2 img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 3px #000;
}
.profile_3 img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid 3px #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="profile_1">
    <img src="http://www.sheffield.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder.png" alt="profile" />
</div>
<div class="profile_2">
    <img src="http://www.sheffield.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder.png" alt="profile" />
</div>
<div class="profile_3">
    <img src="http://www.sheffield.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/placeholder.png" alt="profile" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="center-block"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.center-block{background-image:url(http://b-i.forbesimg.com/assets/images/avatars/generic_profile_image_400.jpg);
            width: 20px;
             height: 20px;
             background-size: cover;
             display: block;
             border-radius: 100px;
             -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/edyvofye/1/)